# Exponential Distribution in place of Uniform Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

I have basic question regarding probability distribution mathematical expressions.
I need to design a model who should calculate probability of choosing seat number in the cinema theater by people and it is told that this follows exponential distribution.

Also given that this probability is also multiplied by some factor $\sum_{i=1}^k AB_i$ .
Now considering N number of seats from 1 to N. I could easily get probability of particular seat selection as $Pu=1/N$ for any one of the seat, being same, if i were using uniform distribution. So the expression for probability would be

$P = Pu $ $\sum_{i=1}^k AB_i$

or

$P = \frac{1}{N} $ $\sum_{i=1}^k AB_i$

But i have to use exponential distribution for seat selection instead of uniform distribution, so how i can get this seat selection probability $Pexp$. i.e

$P= Pexp * \sum_{i=1}^k AB_i$

what would be in place of $Pexp$?
Here $AB_i$ is calculated based on conditional probability.

Comment: the exponential distiribution does not make much sense for this problem, since it is a real-valued distribution, but seat numbers are probably integer valued. The discrete analogue of the exponential distribution is the geometric distribution.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  @ Leander Tilsted Kristensen, in my case assumption is that back row, top seats have high probability of selection, so for seat number 1 to 16, N=16, the seat No.16 has high probability of selection and seat No. 0 has lowest and overall exponential distribution is followed. So as you have mentioned how can i derive expression for _Pexp_ using geometrical distribution?. I really appreciate your interest and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The usual analogy for the geometric distribution is, that we flip coins untill we get a head. In this context, it means that we either pick the seat we are at with probability $p$ or we go on to the next seat with probability $1-p$.

So if we start at seat/row $N$, the probability of sitting here will be $P(X=N)=p$. Continuing on we get
$$P(X=N-1) = P(\text{reject seat }  N \text{ and accept seat } N-1) = p(1-p)$$
$$P(X=N-2) = P(\text{reject seat }  N,N-1 \text{ and accept seat } N-2) = p(1-p)^2$$
$$\dots$$
$$P(X=N-k) = P(\text{reject seat }  N,N-1,\dots,N-(k-1) \text{ and accept seat } N-k) = p(1-p)^k$$
Now it would be tempting to say $P(X=0)=p(1-p)^N$, but this introduces a problem, since $$\sum_{k=0}^N p(1-p)^k< 1.$$
A possible fix would be
$$P(X=0)= 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} p(1-p)^k = (1-p)^N$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so it means i can write $Pexp=(1-p)^N$  and probability equation becomes $P= (1-p)^N * \sum_{i=1}^k AB_i $.                                                  Am i correct in writing this equation?

Comment: if you by $P_{exp}$ mean the probability mass function, then it would be $P_{exp}(N-k) = p(1-p)^k$ for $k=0,1,...,n-1$ and $P_{exp}(0)=(1-p)^N$.

Comment: Now if we have two variables, such as row number $R$ and seat number $S$, then we would have $P(R=r,S=s)=P(R=r | S=s)P(S=s) = P(S=s | R=r)P(R=r)$. So if $R$ follows the geometric rule described above we would have $P(R=N-k,S=s)= P(S=s | R=N-k) p(1-p)^k$ and $P(R=0,S=s)= P(S=s | R=0) (1-p)^N$

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, its really helping me out.  I have just one variable i.e. seat no, ranging from 1 to N.  what can i write in place of $Pexp$.

Comment: The equation of Probability i have needs to multiply $Pexp$ by $\sum_{i=1}^k AB_i$.  So should $Pexp$ be probability mass function or just probability

Comment: The term $P=P_{exp}\sum_{i=1}^k AB_i$ does not in itself describe anything (at least not without further explanation). You cannot just have one probability, you need to calculate the probability of a particular event, such as the probability of choosing a particular seat, hence for $N$ seats we need $N$ probabilities to describe the system (that is we need a probability mass function).

Comment: You have nowhere explained what $\sum_{i=1}^k AB_i$ is. You say that it is a conditional probability, but what is it a probability of and what is it conditioned on.

Comment: The  $\sum_{i=1}^k AB_i$ is probability of a tagged seat to be  a part of a set from where a seat is to be chosen

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^k AB_i $   is actually $\sum_{k=0}^{A-1} \frac{ A-k}{B-k} \binom{B}{k} p^{k} (1-p)^{B-k} $

Comment: What i have found is that $\sum_{i=1}^k AB_i $   is actually $\sum_{k=0}^{|A|-1} \frac{ |A|-k}{|B|-k} \binom{|B|}{k} p^{k} (1-p)^{|B|-k} $ . 

here A is a set containing set of seat numbers to choose from.  A ranges from 1 to A, length of set A, $|A|$ is 1 to A. B is the super set of A with range from 1 to B and containing elements of A. Length of Set B, $|B|$ is 1 to B.           so equation becomes $P=Pexp \sum_{k=0}^{|A|-1} \frac{ |A|-k}{|B|-k} \binom{|B|}{k} p^{k} (1-p)^{|B|-k} $

Comment: Finally considering point mass function can $Pexp$ be written as $Pexp=q(1-q)^{N}$ and finally $P=q(1-q)^{N} \sum_{k=0}^{|A|-1} \frac{ |A|-k}{|B|-k} \binom{|B|}{k} p^{k} (1-p)^{|B|-k} $ with $q$ as probability told by you before, but what value it has?

Comment: q is just a parameter. One way is to say $q\approx \frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ is the average number of seats a person looks at before sitting.  
The probability of picking a particular seat depends heavily on the subset of seats that we choose from, so it should actually be $P_{exp}$ which is the conditional probability (at least if i understood the formulation correctly). So to compute the probability of a seat you have to use $P=\sum_A P(k|A)P(A)$, where we sum over all possible subsets $A$ using som rule for calculating P(A). If $k$ is the $i'th$ element of $A$ then $P(k|A)=q(1-q)^i$.

Comment: Or $P(k|A)=q(1-q)^{|A|-i}$ if we "count backwards". The conditional probabilities makes the problem a lot more complicated, so if you want a better answer you should reformulate the entire question and be a lot more specific and explicit about the problem that you want to solve.

Comment: But I am given condition now that probability of selecting seat has exponential distribution so seat no.1 has lowest and seat no. N has highest probability of being selected, so if still conditional probability is to be used, as you said , then where we can get exponential distribution behaviour for seat selection. Thanks once again for answering my questions.. also what about value of $P(A)$.

Comment: $P(A)$ depends on how the subset $A$ of seats is picked. I have answered how to calculate probabilities based on the geometric distribution, but i cannot answer any more subquestions.